# After submitting contact form message, how do you stop redirecting to root_path?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, contact-form

I'm new to rails and am using this great guide to create a simple contact form in a new app: [contact-form-in-rails-3](http://matharvard.ca/posts/2011/aug/22/contact-form-in-rails-3/)

Everything works but the app I'm building will have a live stream with a contact form for people to submit questions as they watch. The issue is that when I send a message at present, I am redirected to the `root_path`. It is necessary that the app does not redirect or reload the page and that the flash appears in a similar fashion to the validation flash. I understand why this is happening, from the controller below:

```
Class ContactController < ApplicationController

  def new
    @message = Message.new
  end

  def create
    @message = Message.new(params[:message])

    if @message.valid?
      NotificationsMailer.new_message(@message).deliver
      redirect_to(root_path, :notice => "Message was successfully sent.")
    else
      flash.now.alert = "Please fill all fields."
      render :new
    end
  end

end
```

However, when I try to change the redirect line to something such as:

> flash[:notice] = "Message was successfully sent."

The form ceases to submit.

Any advice would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

you need to ad ajax to you form, here is an example of how to add this functionality:

http://stjhimy.com/posts/07-creating-a-100-ajax-crud-using-rails-3-and-unobtrusive-javascript

Comment: Thanks Rodrigo. I will try this out tomorrow and let you know how it works.

Comment: Hi Rodrigo, I've had a closer look at the link you sent. Will this also work for a tableless model?

Comment: Yes it will,  just add the remote attribute to your form,  and create the js response

Answer (score 0):

Or just render the same page, with the given information and the notice message.

What you can do when the redirect occur when you send an ajax is this:

In your controller:

```
respond_to do |format|
    format.js { head :no_content }
    format.html { head :no_content}
end
```

In your ajax:

So basically, event.preventDefault() will inhibit the button to act normally and shouldn't reload the page.

```
$('#selector').click(function(event){
        event.preventDefault();
//Do whatever you want
    });
```

Comment: I've tried this and yes the flash does work now, but it still reloads the page. Unfortunately I can't have this as the live stream would reload as well. Any other advice? Thanks